# Loop inside timber twig file

Tags: php, wordpress, timber

I have a custom post type called products and custom taxonomy called type.

I need to show the list of types and inside three post from each one. Like this

Chicken
{Chicken description}    | Three posts from products in the chicken type
Pork
{Pork description}    | Three posts from products in the pork type

And so for like 6 product types.

So I have this in my wordpress .php file

```
$terms = get_terms('tipo', array('orderby' => 'id'));
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'producto',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tipo',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $term->slug,
            ),
        ),
    );

    $context['product_'.$term->slug] = Timber::get_posts($args);
}

$context['cats'] = Timber::get_terms('tipo', array('orderby' => 'id'));
```

Which should get me product_pork and product_chicken and all else

Inside the `.twig` file I have this

```
{% for cat in cats %}
    {{cat.title}}
    {{cat.description}}
{% endfor %}
```

And everything is fine up until that point but then when I try to do this

```
{% for cat in cats %}
    {{cat.title}}
    {{cat.description}}
    {% for product in cat.slug %}
         {{product.title}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get nothing but if I try this

```
{% for cat in cats %}
    {{cat.title}}
    {{cat.description}}
    {% for product in product_pork %}
         {{product.title}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Of course it works, my question is, is there a way to make it work? Or do you think of another way entirely different? I'm open to suggestions

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line...

```
{% for product in cat.slug %}
```

`cat.slug` is a string, so there's no way to iterate through it. Try this code...

```
$terms = get_terms('tipo', array('orderby' => 'id'));
foreach ($terms as &$term) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'producto',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tipo',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $term->slug,
            ),
        ),
    );

    $term->products = Timber::get_posts($args);
}

$context['cats'] = $terms;
```

#### Twig...

```
{% for cat in cats %}
    {{cat.title}}
    {{cat.description}}
    {% for product in cat.products %}
         {{product.title}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```